# Wait for two actions inside component ngrx store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have 2 actions named METADATA_SUCCESS_ACTION_1 & SUCCESS_ACTION_2.
How can i wait for this 2 actions to complete and then subscribe for the consolidated data.

```js
this.actions
  .pipe(
    ofType(METADATA_SUCCESS_ACTION_1),
    take(1)
  )
  .subscribe((data1: any) => {
    console.log(data1)
  });

this.actions
  .pipe(
    ofType(SUCCESS_ACTION_2),
    take(1)
  )
  .subscribe((data2: any) => {
    console.log(data2)
  });
```

I want to wait for both success to happen and then work on both the data as metadata as well as success data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you can make use of the [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html) operator here (*When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.*). From the documentation:

> **Why use forkJoin?**
>
> This operator is best used when you have a group of observables and
>   only care about the final emitted value of each. One common use case
>   for this is if you wish to issue multiple requests on page load (or
>   some other event) and only want to take action when a response has
>   been receieved for all. In this way it is similar to how you might use
>   `Promise.all`.
>
> Be aware that if any of the inner observables supplied to `forkJoin`
>   error you will lose the value of any other observables that would or
>   have already completed if you do not `catch` the error correctly on the
>   inner observable. If you are only concerned with all inner observables
>   completing successfully you can catch the error on the outside.
>
> It's also worth noting that if you have an observable that emits more
>   than one item, and you are concerned with the previous emissions
>   `forkJoin` is not the correct choice. In these cases you may better off
>   with an operator like `combineLatest` or `zip`.

To use it, you can use the following code for your example above.

```js
forkJoin(
  this.actions.pipe(ofType(METADATA_SUCCESS_ACTION_1), take(1)),
  this.actions.pipe(ofType(SUCCESS_ACTION_2), take(1))
).subscribe(([data1, data2]) => {
  console.log(data1);
  console.log(data2);
})
```